# While loop executing additional even after reaching the condition in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Below query is simple calculation  on multiple tables and inserting the data based on condition to another table

```
DECLARE @CCODE nvarchar(30);
DECLARE @OHQNTY INT;
DECLARE @Itemid nvarchar(30);
DECLARE @ITemlookupcode nvarchar(30);
DECLARE @ExtDescription nvarchar(200);
DECLARE @Department nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @QtyRCV INT;
DECLARE @DAYSCOUNT INT;
DECLARE @DateRecive nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @PoNumber nvarchar(50);



DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR
SELECT [Code],[Onhand] FROM [dbo].[vwStockOnHand] WHERE code <300000;

OPEN CUR

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @CCODE,@OHQNTY
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN 
    WHILE(@OHQNTY>0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP(1) @Itemid=[Itemid],@PoNumber=[PoNumber],@ITemlookupcode=[ITemlookupcode],
                    @ExtDescription=[ExtDescription],
                    @Department=[Department],@QtyRCV=[QtyRCV],@DateRecive=[DateRecive]
                    FROM [dbo].[StockIn]
                    WHERE ITemlookupcode=@CCODE AND [QtyRCV]>0
                    ORDER BY DateRecive DESC, PoNumber ASC;

        SET @DAYSCOUNT= DATEDIFF(DAY,MAX(@DateRecive),GETDATE());

        IF (@QtyRCV >= @OHQNTY AND @OHQNTY>0)
            BEGIN
                -- INSERTING DATA
                INSERT INTO [dbo].StockAging 
                (Itemid,ITemlookupcode,ExtDescription,Department,QtyRCV,DateRecive,DaysCount)
                VALUES(@Itemid,@ITemlookupcode,@ExtDescription,@Department,@OHQNTY,@DateRecive,@DAYSCOUNT)

                -- UPDATING  
                UPDATE  [dbo].[StockOnHand]
                SET [Onhand]=0 
                FROM [dbo].[StockOnHand]
                WHERE [Code]=@CCODE;

                UPDATE  [dbo].[StockIn]
                SET [QtyRCV]=0 
                FROM [dbo].[StockIn]
                WHERE ITemlookupcode=@CCODE AND PoNumber=@PoNumber;

                SET @OHQNTY=0;
            END 
        ELSE IF (@OHQNTY > 0)
            BEGIN
                -- INSERTING DATA
                INSERT INTO [dbo].StockAging 
                (Itemid,ITemlookupcode,ExtDescription,Department,QtyRCV,DateRecive,DaysCount)
                VALUES(@Itemid,@ITemlookupcode,@ExtDescription,@Department,@QtyRCV,@DateRecive,@DAYSCOUNT) 

                -- UPDATING  
                UPDATE  [dbo].[StockOnHand]
                SET [Onhand]=[Onhand]-@QtyRCV FROM [dbo].[StockOnHand]
                WHERE [Code]=@CCODE;

                -- UPDATING  
                UPDATE  [dbo].[StockIn]
                SET [QtyRCV]=0 FROM [dbo].[StockIn]
                WHERE ITemlookupcode=@CCODE AND PoNumber=@PoNumber;

                SET @OHQNTY=@OHQNTY-@QtyRCV;

            END
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @CCODE,@OHQNTY
END
    CLOSE CUR 
    DEALLOCATE CUR
```

I think the code is self explanatory ,

Issue I'm facing is even after reaching condition **@OHQNTY>0** It is passing through the loop again. I know there is some issue with the looping, but couldn't find where I'm missing the logic.
Here [image: Result]is the result of the query, the below one with RecvdQty=9 is additional

Comment: Your code would be a *lot* simpler and faster if you used `UPDATE`, `INSERT` statements with the proper `WHERE` and join clauses. Cursor are almost always the wrong solution for SQL problems

Answer (score 1):

in  `IF (@QtyRCV >= @OHQNTY AND @OHQNTY>0)`

you update

```
UPDATE  [dbo].[StockIn]
SET [QtyRCV]=0 
FROM [dbo].[StockIn]
WHERE ITemlookupcode=@CCODE AND PoNumber=@PoNumber;
```

but you have "used" only `@OHQNTY` so I think you should

```
UPDATE  [dbo].[StockIn]
SET [QtyRCV]=[QtyRCV]- @OHQNTY 
FROM [dbo].[StockIn]
WHERE ITemlookupcode=@CCODE AND PoNumber=@PoNumber;
```

also, you have your IF condition like that

```
IF (@QtyRCV >= @OHQNTY AND @OHQNTY>0) BEGIN
...
END ELSE IF (@OHQNTY > 0) BEGIN
...
END
```

but `@OHQNTY > 0` is useless, it should be

```
IF (@QtyRCV >= @OHQNTY) BEGIN
...
END ELSE BEGIN
...
END
```

finally I will write it this way

```
IF (@QtyRCV >= @OHQNTY) BEGIN
  @QtyUsed = @OHQNTY
END ELSE BEGIN
  @QtyUsed = @QtyRCV
END

-- INSERTING DATA
INSERT INTO [dbo].StockAging 
(Itemid, ITemlookupcode, ExtDescription, Department, QtyRCV, DateRecive, DaysCount)
VALUES(@Itemid, @ITemlookupcode, @ExtDescription, @Department, @QtyUsed, @DateRecive, @DAYSCOUNT)

-- UPDATING  
UPDATE [dbo].[StockOnHand]
SET [Onhand] = [Onhand] - @QtyUsed
WHERE [Code]=@CCODE;

UPDATE [dbo].[StockIn]
SET [QtyRCV] = [QtyRCV] - @QtyUsed
WHERE ITemlookupcode=@CCODE AND PoNumber=@PoNumber;

SET @OHQNTY = @OHQNTY - @QtyUsed;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see issue  in `If` Clause..

```
IF (@QtyRCV >= @OHQNTY AND @OHQNTY>0)
Begin
set @OHQNTY=0
End
```

When `If` Clause is not satisfied ,your while loop keeps on executing..move setting of @`OHQNTY`  to outside of If Clause

Comment: But insertion happening inside if loop so if that condition fails it shouldn't insert any data . am I right?

Comment: I am not sure about your data,I don't see any issue moving `set @OHQNTY=0` to outside of If Clause